# What stops someone from faking a rating on OTC web of trust?

Tags: exchanges, otc

What mechanisms does [OTC web of trust](http://wiki.bitcoin-otc.com/wiki/OTC_Rating_System) have against someone creating several accounts and trading between with themselves over a period of time, giving each other perfect ratings.

Answer (score 4):

The global ratings are fairly easy to manipulate as you describe, and it has been done before. There is some minor protection provided by the requirement that you need a positive OTC rating to rate anyone else.

#bitcoin-otc also supports "trust rating" ([example](http://serajewelks.bitcoin-otc.com/trustgraph.php?source=theymos&dest=Keefe)) which can't be easily manipulated.